# Uninstalling a eclipse manually (no package manager)

Tags: uninstall, eclipse, software-uninstall

Good day all,
I've installed eclipse(4.7) by downloading, extracting and installing the .tar.xx files from the website, not using the package manager. I would like to remove it but have no idea how. Usually I find an uninstall.sh script in the program folder that handles uninstalling but this is not the case. How would I go about removing the software?

Note:It was not as simple as extracting the files.  I ran a bash script that started a setup wizard which copied files, downloaded files, possibly modified some system variables.

lubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you had installed eclipse by just extracting files . if this is the case then you can simply delete those extracted files .

if you ran some install.sh script and not finding uninstall.sh then type the following commands

```
whereis eclipse
which eclipse
```

By this you will get idea of where are files are installed and thus you can remove those file.if you are seeing orphan desktop entry of your software then read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40884/how-can-i-remove-orphaned-start-menu-entries)

Also eclipse stores its configuration files in ~/.eclipse folder which you might want remove cause they can clash with eclipse installation from apt repos

EDIT:-

if environment variable are set in ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile and in some cases  /etc/environment . you can unset those

Comment: Hi Smit, thanks for response. I modified the question. Also I checked the contents of the folders the sum comes to around 30 mb which can't be the full installation. Or could it?

Comment: @Clintus ~/.eclipse is not installation folder . it is configuration folder . my ~/.eclipse is of size 189MB Cause i have installed so many plugins .You can remove it safely but it wont uninstall eclipse. to uninstall eclipse follow the step I mentioned when there is no uninstall.sh. : ) Happy to help

Comment: @Clintus Also I suggest you to not use these installers for Linux. just download eclipse in tar.gz format ,extract it and start using.