# Remove menu icons of uninstalled applications

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, appmenu

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 18.04.
Under my Graphics dropdown menu I still have old application icons to uninstalled applications. How do I remove these icons?

[image: Graphics dropdown menu]

Comment: Do you remember how do you installed these programs?

Comment: I still do not understand how do you installed these applications. I can not invent new method (or improve existing) until your provide more details.

Comment: Take a look at [this good answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40884/how-can-i-remove-orphaned-start-menu-entries#answer-44303) for such orphaned entries.

Answer (score 1):

## GUI method

Make right click on *Applications* menu, click *Edit Menus* to run "easy MATE menu editing tool" (*System->Preferences->Look and Feel->Main Menu* or `mozo` executable):

[image: Mozo main menu]

and remove checkboxes in the *Graphics* category in *Show* column.

## Console method

Usually applications from Wine or other third-party source save `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

You can try to find them here with the command below:

```
grep -ir -E "Hiero|Nuke" ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Then carefully remove desktop-files of really removed applications.

Comment: Thanks but neither method works for me. Broken icons don't show up in easy Mate editing tool and using Console method No such file or directory

Comment: OP For Ubuntu users it is /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 1):

This software appears to only be supported for CentOS (not Ubuntu) linux, which suggests the desktop files may have been placed in a location which that distro uses.  Take a peek in these folders for Nuke related desktop files:

```
/usr/share/desktop-directories
/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged
/usr/share/applications
```

Comment: why the downvote?  just trying to understand why this is not helpful.