# How to remove icon of uninstalled app?

Tags: icons, .desktop, software-uninstall

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1, the other day I installed Ark from the Ubuntu Software app but ended up uninstalling it after a couple minutes because it wasn't working well.

Recently I noticed that the icon is still there so now I'm wondering how to remove it. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 11):

the standard places where *.desktop-Files are stored are:

`/usr/share/applications/` and

`~/.local/share/applications/`

To check if there is an ark in these folders I'd in a Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) do a:

`ls -la /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i 'ark'` and

`ls -la ~/.local/share/applications/ | grep -i 'ark'`

if so I'd delete it with `sudo rm <pathtofile>/<*.desktop-file>`, `sudo` is not necessary when deleting the file in your home folder.

Afterwards, or even if there is no arc*.desktop-File I'd do a forced update to my menu via:

`sudo xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate --mode system`

Comment: Hi! When I run `ls -la /usr/share/applications/ | grep -i 'ark'` and `ls -la ~/.local/share/applications/ | grep -i 'ark'` nothing happens. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: no , nothing is wrong, this simple means there aren't any. then a simple `sudo xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate --mode system`should do the trick

Comment: ps: stumbled over this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/40884/how-can-i-remove-orphaned-start-menu-entries

Comment: Do I have to reboot after trying `sudo xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate --mode system` ?

Comment: sorry forgot, a simple logout should be enough

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work out :/ What can I try now?
I took a look at that link you gave me, but that didn't work either

Comment: For me the desktop file was at `/usr/local/share/applications`.

Answer (score -2):

If you're command-line challenged, you could:

1. Position the cursor over the unwanted icon.
2. Hold down the Right mouse button. This will bring up a menu.
3. Scroll down to "`Move to Trash`", and release the mouse button.

Comment: You mean after opening the correct location in file manager? Otherwise this may very well be interpreted as "*right clicking on the app icon in 'Show Applications'*" (as in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuFUK.png)) which I believe won't work.

Comment: How can I find the location in file manager?